# Using a for loop and if statement in VB

Tags: vba, if-statement, for-loop

I am trying to write a for loop that goes from 1 to 125 and does the same stuff based off of each number* unless it is 1 of 8 numbers (24, 48, 63, 75, 104, 110, 114, 119) in which case it does nothing. Other than writing an if statement after the for loop that says:

```
If g <> 24 and g <> 48 and... and g <> 119 Then 
   Do stuff
End If
```

Is there a cleaner way to get the code to do what I want?

Answer (score 1):

To make it clearer as to what is happening you could use a Select Case:

```
Select Case g
    Case 24, 48, 63, 75, 104, 110, 114, 119
        ' do nothing
    Case Else
        ' do stuff
End Select
```

Answer (score 1):

A [`Select Case`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cy37t14y.aspx) is a nice way to do it

```
  Dim i As Integer

  For i = 1 To 125
    Select Case i
      Case 24, 48, 63, 75, 104, 110, 114, 119
        'skip
      Case Else
        'your code
    End Select
  Next
```

Answer (score -1):

You can make a list (array) with the exceptions and check in the for loop if the index is contained in the array and then skip the operation for that index.

pseudo code (c#)

```
list = new List(){24, 48, 63, 75};

for(int=index; index<=125; index++)
{   
  if(list.Contains(index))
    continue;

  // Do some operation
}
```